# Setting null as value in numeric data types in Hive table using spark

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am looking for a solution where I need to populate null in numeric fields which have no value in it using Spark. The code which I have written is as below:

```
val myDF = sqlContext.sql("from mystg.my_acct_table select id,amt,tot_amt where id=12345")
myDF.map(row => {val row1 = row.getAs[Double]("tot_amt")
      val my_tot_amt = {
          if(row1.isNaN())
              null.asInstanceOf[Double]
          else
              Math.abs(row1.toDouble)
        }
    Row(row(0),row(1),my_tot_amt)
   })
```

I also tried by putting the above logic in Row(row(0),row(1),my_tot_amt).

```
  Row(row(0),row(1),(if(row1.isNaN())
                    null.asInstanceOf[Double]
                else
                    Math.abs(row1.toDouble)))
```

But I am getting the output as 
     | 8687992537618075    | 1163.35      | 0.0 |

The expected output is 
     | 8687992537618075    | 1163.35      | null |

Answer (score 1):

`null.asInstanceOf[Double]` is `0.0`. Just don't cast it:

```
val my_tot_amt = if(row1.isNaN())
  null
else
  Math.abs(row1.toDouble)
```

should work (this makes the type of `my_tot_amt` `Any`; `val my_tot_amt: java.lang.Double = ...` is more precise, but shouldn't be necessary in this specific case).

Also, I think you'll get `0.0` where `row("tot_amt")` is already `null`; is this intentional?

Comment: When I check the value in hive it comes as empty i.e. " " it is not populated as null in that field. So I need to check for such records and update the value to null. Yes I dont want the value as 0.0 but it should be null.